# Apache Virtual Host IP Works but not ServerName

Tags: apache, wamp, virtualhost, hosts, server-name

I am using Wamp.
My Apache Server is running on port 90.
I Tried adding a virtual host by doing the following steps:

1)Removed the comment from the line `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` line in my Apache httpd.conf file.

2)I Added the following code to my `C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:90>
ServerAdmin admin@laravel.dev
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/laravel/public"
ServerName laravel.dev
ServerAlias www.laravel.dev
ErrorLog "logs/laravel.dev.log"
CustomLog "logs/dummy-laravel.dev.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:90>
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"
</VirtualHost>
```

3)I made changes to my windows hosts file.This is the content of my hosts file

```
127.0.0.1:90  localhost
127.0.0.1:90 laravel.dev
127.0.0.1:90 www.laravel.dev
```

Now `localhost:90` will Redirect to my `C:/wamp/www` and `127.0.0.1:90` will Redirect to my `C:/wamp/www/laravel/public` but **both `laravel.dev` and `www.laravel.dev` are not working**
I get the message `Oops! Google Chrome could not find laravel.dev` in my chrome.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: I found out that i cannot add IP with Ports inside hosts file.
So i just changed `127.0.0.1:90 laravel.dev` TO `127.0.0.1 laravel.dev`. Now my when i try `laravel.dev` it goes to my Default IIS homepage which uses Port 80 and `laravel.dev:90` is pointing to my laravel's public folder. Is there anyway i can route `laravel.dev ` to `c:/wamp/www/laravel/public` without using any mentioning any prots in the addressbar of my browser?

Comment: This might have a clue: http://serverfault.com/questions/85078/how-to-forward-dns-alias-to-hostnameport

Comment: I assume you rebooted or restarted the `DNS Client` service after changing the `HOSTS` file?